# Returning an array using php in a better format

Tags: php, arrays, format

I have a form that I allows the user to create a list of names. I need to also allow them to designate an rsvp status for an event for each name.

Here is the section of the form:

```
<li>
<div id="dynamicInput">
          Name 1<br><input type="text" name="myInputs[]">   Attending Brunch? Yes<input name="attending[]" type="checkbox" value="Attending Brunch" />  No<input name="notattending[]" type="checkbox" value="Not Attending Brunch" /><br>
           Name 2<br><input type="text" name="myInputs[]">   Attending Brunch? Yes<input name="attending[]" type="checkbox" value="Attending Brunch" />  No<input name="notattending[]" type="checkbox" value="Not Attending Brunch" /><br>
            Name 3<br><input type="text" name="myInputs[]">   Attending Brunch? Yes<input name="attending[]" type="checkbox" value="Attending Brunch" />  No<input name="notattending[]" type="checkbox" value="Not Attending Brunch" /><br>
             Name 4<br><input type="text" name="myInputs[]">   Attending Brunch? Yes<input name="attending[]" type="checkbox" value="Attending Brunch" />  No<input name="notattending[]" type="checkbox" value="Not Attending Brunch" /><br>
              Name 5<br><input type="text" name="myInputs[]">   Attending Brunch? Yes<input name="attending[]" type="checkbox" value="Attending Brunch" />  No<input name="notattending[]" type="checkbox" value="Not Attending Brunch" /><br>
     </div>
     <input type="button" value="Add another volunteer" onClick="addInput('dynamicInput');">
 </li>
```

This is the php that is returning the information in an email:

```
$myInputs = $_POST['myInputs'];
foreach ($myInputs as $eachInput) {
     $message .= $eachInput . " - " ;
}

$attending = $_POST['attending'];
foreach ($attending as $moreInput) {
     $message .= $moreInput . "<br><br>";
}

$notattending = $_POST['notattending'];
foreach ($notattending as $moreInput) {
     $message .= $moreInput . "<br><br>";
}


$contact = $_POST['contact'];
$from = "$name <$email>";
$to = $_POST['recipient']; //"kim@ka-kingdesigns.com";
$subject = "Day of Caring Team Registration".$_POST['subject'];
$comments = "
<strong>Team Members</strong><br> {$message}<br><br>;
```

Right now it return info entered like this:

**Team Members** Kim - Attending Brunch - Donovan - - - - Not Attending Brunch

I need it to return like this:

**Team Members** 
Kim - Attending Brunch
Donovan - Not Attending Brunch

Can anyone help?

Comment: Why do you have two checkboxes for attending and not attending? Wouldn't it be easier to have radio buttons instead? Also, the names you're giving in the first line for your checkboxes are `myInputs[]` - it's `attending[]` and `notattending[]` for the rest. Is that a typo?

Comment: Yes, that's a typo. Sorry about that. Maybe radio buttons would be better. Any thoughts on the php formatting?

Answer (score 0):

As things stand, you're looping through the whole list of names of people on the form; then you're looping through the list of attendees; then you're looping though the list of non-attendees.

I'd suggest explicitly numbering the fields:

```
Name 1<br><input type="text" name="name_1">   
Attending Brunch? Yes<input name="attending_1" type="radio" value="Yes" />  
No<input name="attending_1" type="radio" value="No" /><br>
```

That makes handling the data a lot easier:

```
$count = 1;

while (isset($_POST["name_" . $count])) {
    $message .= $_POST["name_" . $count] . " - " $_POST["attending_" . $count] . "\n";
}
```

(Apologies if the syntax is a little off - I've been writing perl all day, and the syntax is close enough to cause issues when I try to switch back)

If you want to add an extra entry using javascript, it will just need to loop through the form to find the highest existing entry, and use the next available number to generate the field names.

Comment: I couldn't get that to work, and I don't know enough to fix it. Thank you for the effort, though!

Comment: I've fixed one obvious error - do you want to see if it works better now?